# IntelliJ Live Template as method

Tags: java, intellij-idea, live-templates

I would like to create a Live Template that is triggered after typing the dot of an array, in a similar way as **stream** converts **myarray.stream** to **Arrays.stream(mystream)**.

How can I do that?

Comment: Postfix completion can be implemented only as a plug-in.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know it was called "Postfix completion". Now I can see there is no way to add custom ones. Saved me a lot of time.

Comment: You can submit a feature request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA and our developers will add more templates.

Answer (score 4):

This is now implemented in IntelliJ 2018.1: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122443

[image: Postfix Completion]